# What is the difference between an SFM and an SFU?

Tags: webrtc, real-time, media, rtp

If the question doesn't belong on stackoverflow, sorry for the noise. I couldn't find a better suiting site within stackexchange.

## Question

There are definitions of:

1. Selective Forwarding Middlebox (abbreviated SFM) defined in [RFC 7667 Section 3.7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7667#section-3.7)
2. Selective Forwarding Unit (abbreviated SFU) defined in [WebRTC Glossary](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/)

What is the difference of these things? Are they essentially the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. The usage of SFU in a WebRTC context predates RFC 7667 and is hence a much more commonly used term (ironically the RFC itself still mentions 'SFU' in one place without defining the term).

See also [this commit](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-svc/commit/3b40919755980eaa58c88110785f5175480bbe85) which does a simple replace of SFU with SFM.